# AdSense for single page utility web application?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I have a web site that exists to provide a useful, but somewhat simple, facility.  It is implemented as a single page that contains a Javascript application along with documentation on how to use it and advice for using the results that it produces.  In order to monetize the application, I applied for an AdSense account, but was rejected due to "insufficient content". As my site primarily exists to provide an interactive service, I'm not sure what content I could realistically add to it that is not already there (it has around 600 words of documentation and advice).   What options do I have that might help the site be accepted for AdSense?  Or would I be better off looking for another ad network that may be more accepting of this non-text-content-based site?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any other blog or some website where there is a ton of content, use that site to apply for Adsense. Once you get approved, you can add up to 500 sites in that account (please tell me the correct number if you find any official evidence) and serve ads on those websites.

If you don't have any other website, just add a /blog to your web application, write two to three detailed articles and then try again. They'll get you approved.

But Adsense being a CPC (and CPM) network, you won't earn much.

You can use affiliate programs of products related to your niche to make just a lot more money than Adsense.

Comment: I don't currently have an appropriate site, but that certainly seems worth thinking about.  As for affiliate programs, I've already signed up for Amazon and placed a few links to relevant products that my site visitors may want, and do expect that these will provide the majority of my income. :)

Comment: "Up to 100 sites per account" source?

Comment: @marcanuy When I was using Adsense (more than two years ago), the place where you added more domains to put ads on showed a message like "99 sites more can be added" or similar.

Thanks for pointing out, though, I researched on the topic after reading your comment, and it seems like the limit has changed to 500 sites. 

Unfortunately, I didn't find any official source. I am editing the answer to notify this.

Comment: @RohanShah  I never heard about that limit before and couldn't find anything related so it is good to know, thanks for clarifying.